# Don't show this again - checkbox hierarchy in a popup

Tags: popup

I notice that the 'Don't show this again' checkbox is often placed before the action buttons (e.g. CANCEL and OK) which are placed further down and aligned to the right. Is this some sort of standard or is there some study on this placement?

[image]

Comment: I'm not aware of standardization or studies, but it looks like the most logical placement. Do you have reasons to put it elsewhere? Have you done any observational user studies to see how users respond to it at different locations?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I do not have any studies on this at the moment, but I was asked why the checkbox is located before the action buttons and not after.

In a logic of importance, the buttons should be placed first (I want to make the user click YES, for example) and then finally the checkbox, but seeing Microsoft, Apple, Google and others they all seem to use the same hierarchy: checkbox and then buttons.

I would think that if such companies have adopted this layout, there would be some articles or studies about it. But I can't find any at the moment.

Comment: I gather the problem you have with this is that the option to not show again is less important that choosing No or Yes, and you think it may be better to put the option last. That did not occur to me. I suggest you add the clarification to your question to help others like me.

Comment: "I want...the user [to] click YES...and then finally the checkbox..." I assume clicking No or Yes closes the modal—am I mistaken??

Answer (score 1):

This mostly about is simple reading order.

We are trained (by exposure) to deal with things in the order we read them. Westernised users start at the top left-hand corner of the page and work their way down line by line or quadrant by quadrant depending on the page structure, content, and the reader's intention. This is also known as [Gutenberg Reading Gravity](https://medium.com/user-experience-3/the-gutenberg-diagram-in-web-design-e5347c172627) and goes some way to explaining why CTAs are best placed in the bottom right corner for westernised audiences.

Areas of strong colour also attract the user's eye, dragging them away from less colourful things.

If the checkbox came AFTER the buttons, there is a strong likelihood that the majority of users would see the button and click it before reading the checkbox label.

Placing the checkbox BEFORE the button raises the chance that users will read that before clicking the button.

You can, of course, use this to manipulate your users into acting in specific ways depending on your business needs.

Comment: I used the term "westernised users" here to differentiate those users who are ONLY exposed to right-to-left or other systems of reading - those cultures will have a different reading gravity based on their reading order.